# Gap under top border of table while using \hhline

Tags: tables, hhline

I am using the code below to generate a table. But there is some gap after the first border line. It seems the gap will disappear if I change all the `\hhline` to `\hline` or `\cline` in the table. I am wondering what the problem is and how to remove this gap while still using `\hhline`? Thanks. (PS: I have to use `\hhline` to avoid the borders of certain colored cells being covered by the color.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
 \small
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{=====}
 \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{YES}} & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & \cellcolor{gray!20}b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

When I comment out the package `arydshln`, the gap disappears. There seems to be some conflict here. But I have to use `arydshln` to draw some dashed line, e.g. `\cdashline{1-2}`. Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete small document that makes the image shown, I guessed `\usepackage{hhline,graphicx,multirow,colortbl,xcolor}` but that still leaves undefined commands so it's impossible to even start to debug

Comment: I have edited to include all the packages used. It seems there is some package after adding which the gap would appear.

Comment: That is so weird. I have just copied and run the code posted on my laptop. It indeed produces a gap. I am using Kile 2.1.3.

Comment: I think I have found the crux. When I comment out the package `arydshln`, the gap disappears. But I have to use `arydshln` to draw some dashed line, e.g. `\cdashline{1-2}`.

Comment: Sorry The last version does give the gap (my error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some weird interaction with `arydshln`  here I just add some negative space to close the gap and add an invisible 0-width rule to lengthen the visible rules in the first row,

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
 \small
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\noalign{\vskip-4pt}
 \rule{0pt}{14pt} & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{=====}
 \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{YES}} & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & \cellcolor{gray!20}b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hhline{~----}
 & a & b & c & d\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it seems some adjustment would be needed to make a "perfect" position of the top border. Also, the border may touch the text in the table first than the vertical border, which does not look good. I guess I will just give up `arydshln` and try to find some alternative to `\cdashline`.